# CSS class not loading but everything else is

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with the class `boxPad` not wanting to load all of the other class's etc are showing in the inspecter panel just not `boxPad` why?

**HTML:**

`<div class="infusion-holder yes boxPad">Some Info</div>`

**CSS:**

```
.infusion-holder{display:none;}
.yes{display:block !important;}
.infusion-holder .yes .boxPad {padding-bottom:155px;}
.infusion-holder h3.ftitle{margin-bottom:10px !important;}
.infusion-holder form.infusion-form{border-top:1px solid #fff; padding-top:20px;}
.infusion-submit p{text-align:center; color:#fff; font-size:18px;}
.fdesc{padding-bottom:15px;}
.infusion-holder .infusion-submit input{margin-top:0px !important;}
.box1 form.infusion-form {display:inline-block; float:left; padding:0 15px 155px 0; border-top:none;}
.box2 form.infusion-form {display:inline-block; float:left; padding:0 15px 155px 0; border-top:none;}
.box3 form.infusion-form {display:inline-block; float:left; padding:0 15px 155px 0; border-top:none;}
```

**Mark Up:**
`

```
    <div class="box1">
        <form class="infusion-form" action="#">
            <div class="infusion-submit">
                <p></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Download PDF" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
        <form class="infusion-form" action="#">
            <div class="infusion-submit">
                <p></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Download PDF" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
        <form class="infusion-form" action="#">
            <div class="infusion-submit">
                <p></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Download PDF" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

`

Answer (score 3):

Selector `.infusion-holder .yes .boxPad {}` is selecting an element with class `boxPad` inside element with class `yes` inside element with class `infusion-holder`.

To select element with all three classes like your example- you need to use  selector

```
.infusion-holder.yes.boxPad {}
```